# Segfault in a simple program using Qt on ARM

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, arm

I'm trying to use Qt 4.7.4 on an ARM system, in order to display a graphic application on a touchscreen.

My ARM card embeds a Linux system; we use the Linux framebuffer to send information to the screen, and tslib+usbtouchscreen drivers to get the touch information.

I'm able to cross-compile Qt and put the library on my system. But when I launch my test program, I get a segfault every time at the same moment (without logical reason).

To begin with, here is my test program (you can see it's very basic, no reason to segfault) :

```
#include <QMessageBox> 
#include <QApplication>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText( "Hello world !" );
    msgBox.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The segfault appends during the `show()` call, in fact (thanks to some debugging), I realized it appends during the loading of font cache. Moreover, adding a `printf()` just after the call to `localData()` makes the segfault disappear... for a moment! However, when I close the application, I get the segfault anyway.

In `Qt/gui/text/qfont.cpp` line 2615, adding a `printf()` after `theFontCache()->loadData()` temporarily resolves the problem:

```
QFontCache *QFontCache::instance()
{
    QFontCache *&fontCache = theFontCache()->localData();

    if (!fontCache) {
        fontCache = new QFontCache;
    }

return fontCache;
}
```

Here is my `./configure` command line :

`./configure -release -shared -fast -no-largefile -exceptions -no-accessibility -no-stl -no-qt3support -no-xmlpatterns -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-svg -no-webkit -no-declarative -no-declarative-debug -no-glib -no-cups -no-scripttools -no-script -no-audio-backend -no-multimedia -no-nis -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-str-g++ -little-endian -no-gfx-multiscreen -prefix /usr -qconfig mbxconfig -nomake examples -nomake demos -depths 16 -qt-mouse-tslib -confirm-license -opensource`

I tried to configure with `-no-freetype`; nothing changed. I also tried to force the font, but no success neither. I also tried `echo 3 > /proc/cpu/alignment` but I didn't find any alignment problem that way. One solution that I would try: compile without the compiler optimization - but I apparently didn't change the right options, since it still compiles with `-O2`. My GCC version is 4.2.3.

Last, my strace before the segfault :

```
open("/dev/psaux", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/input/mice", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/tty0", O_RDWR)               = 8
fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
ioctl(8, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(8, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(8, KDGKBMODE, 0x1a21c)            = 0
ioctl(8, KDSKBMODE, 0x2)                = 0
ioctl(8, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(8, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x40bb3d68, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {0x40bb3d68, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(8, VIDIOC_RESERVED or VT_GETMODE, 0xbedbb598) = 0
ioctl(8, VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT or VT_SETMODE, 0xbedbb598) = 0
ioctl(8, VT_GETSTATE, 0xbedbb588)       = 0
gettimeofday({1321521340, 447374}, NULL) = 0
brk(0x1d000)                            = 0x1d000
open("/proc/self/auxv", O_RDONLY)       = 9
fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
read(9, "\20\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\21\0\0\0d\0\0\0\3\0\0\0004\200\0\0\4"..., 256) = 128
read(9, ""..., 256)                     = 0
close(9)                                = 0
write(4, "\0"..., 1)                    = 1
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {SIG_DFL, [SEGV], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, {0x40142d48, [SEGV], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, 8) = 0
ioctl(8, KDSKBMODE, 0x3)                = 0
ioctl(8, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(8, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
ioctl(7, KDSETMODE, 0)                  = 0
write(7, "\33[9;15]\33[?33h\33[?25h\33[?0c\0"..., 25) = 25
close(7)                                = 0
kill(29810, SIGSEGV)                    = 0
sigreturn()                             = ? (mask now [])
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

On the ARM system, I don't have enough space to compile with debug so that's why it's directly in release.

Comment: Problem solved after disabling gcc -O2 optimization ; new problem is that the lib are pretty heavy now, but that's another question :-°

For those who are interested, in order to change the optimization option when compiling Qt, you need to alter *mkspecs/common/g++.conf* and modify the CFLAGS

Comment: Related: http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/1854

Comment: Actually I think there might be a stack corruption induced by Qt code ; unfortunately, I don't know how to debug this.. Suppressing all optimizations is quite bad for us, 'cause we'd like to use the less memory possible. Adding a printf() to avoid the bug is just a temporary solution, 'cause the application can still crash anytime.

Any idea ?

Comment: It looks like reverting to Qt 4.6.3 worked well for the guys in the above link.  I've personally written apps for Qt 4.6.2 that have worked well across ARM linux devices.  I cross-compiled with the arm-none-linux-gnueabi 4.3.2 toolchain, and did have to make heavy edits to the mkspecs.  I think the appropriate args were `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t`

Comment: "space to compile with debug" - you can compile only some files with debug (this require hacking of QT build system or manual recompiling of some files with -g option). Or you can try to setup ARM emulated system with qemu - it will have a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to bug report linked in some pages https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13441

SEGV is in  ../3rdparty/harfbuzz/src/harfbuzz-* (two backtraces are posted and both ended in  `../3rdparty/harfbuzz/src/harfbuzz-gsub.c`)

So, you should try to rebuild only this 3rd party library "harfbuzz" with `-g -O2` and `-g -O0`. As it is 3rdparty, it has its own build system, and I think it can be changed easily.

When you will prove that your bug is in this library too and that it depends on -O2/-O0 flag, you can:

- find an exact place of SEGV and do an backtrace from GDB;
- do an `x/i $pc` from GDB and `info reg` to see where is the SEGV data is and what is the action.
- find an exact file/function with bug and do a diff of disassembled function between -O0 and -O2 versions
- post both disassembly here or in QT bugtracker
- file a bug on harfbuzz or GCC

Also, the strace is almost not interesting and the gdb's backtrace is.

Update from Jérémy Dutheil: "Simply by compiling with -Os option : no more segfault, and very small size for libs! " -- So if O2 fails, O1 and/or Os should be tried too.

Comment: The thing is I don't think it's caused by harfbuzz because I try to configure with the -no-freetype option and it didn't change anything. :/ Moreover, we sadly don't have GDB on our system. I'll try to debug harfbuzz anyway, but I don't think it is the reason.
Thanks !

Comment: The gerenic way is 1) find a debugger (e.g. do a coredump and analyze it on other system) or repeat the situation in qemu, which is gdb-remote compatible) 2) try to locate, which file / component has an error. You have and -O0/-O2 detector and can compile part of QT with O2, other part with O0

Comment: Finally, we succeeded in achieving what we want : small libs and no segfault. Simply by compiling with -Os option : no more segfault, and very small size for libs! 
If I have the time one of this day, I'll try to understand the previous bug but for now it's solved so.. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Jérémy Add this info as an answer!